# How to install mcrypt on RHEL5

Tags: rhel5, mcrypt

We have an RHEL5 server that I'm trying to install PHP-Mcrypt on and I'm stuck when I tried to run ./configure for mcrypt source files.

I was using this guide: http://atlantatechpro.com/howtos/howtoslinux/howtosmhashmcrypt

When I try to install (./configure) mcrypt, I get this

> checking for libmcrypt - version >= 2.5.0... no
>
> Could not run libmcrypt test program, checking why...
> The test program compiled, but did not run. This usually means
> that the run-time linker is not finding LIBMCRYPT or finding the wrong
> version of LIBMCRYPT. If it is not finding LIBMCRYPT, you'll need to set your
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, or edit /etc/ld.so.conf to point
> to the installed location  Also, make sure you have run ldconfig if that
> is required on your system
>
> If you have an old version installed, it is best to remove it, although
> you may also be able to get things to work by modifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> configure: error: *** libmcrypt was not found

I also made a file at `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libmcrypt.conf` with `/usr/local/libmcrypt` in it and ran `/sbin/ldconfig`

I might have screwed things up by trying to reinstall libmcrypt without the configure arguments.

Any suggestions on what to do now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't try to compile yourself, you'll just get yourself into trouble that way. (and even if you were compiling yourself, you should compile into RPMs and install those, instead of installing directly to the systems).  First, try to find all the files you've installed yourself and remove them (check that they don't belong to a system package with `rpm -qf /file`.)

EPEL is the third-party source for RHEL packages that's closest to being "official", so I suggest that: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#howtouse

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
yum install php-mcrypt
```

(the exact RPM url changes with time as updates happen and is different for different RHEL versions, so check the [EPEL FAQ](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#howtouse) to get the correct link.)

The first step sets you up with EPEL, the second installs PHP Mcrypt and all its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow. Is there an easy way to find out and remove all the files that I already tied to install?

Comment: No, there really isn't any reliable, easy, generic way. Which is a big reason to go with RPM instead of direct compile+install.  It sounds like you installed everything into /usr/local, so it shouldn't be too hard...

Comment: `make uninstall` is supported in a lot of Makefiles these days.  Otherwise, you just remove all the files installed from the output of `make install`.

Comment: For people viewing this from Jan 2012 onwards, this URL should (hopefully) work: http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm

Comment: @Jamie: The question was about RHEL5, not RHEL6. Just now I updated the example URL and made it clearer that somebody should really check that EPEL FAQ to get the right URL.

Comment: @freiheit you're completely right. I just want to make it clear for people who drift onto this thread from Google

Comment: @Jamie: Feel free to make an edit to the answer itself to make that clearer

Answer (score 0):

http://www.notesbit.com/index.php/web-mysql/web-scripts/how-to-install-mcrypt-in-linux-cent-os-and-recompile-php/

or

install DAG rpm and then

yum install mhash
yum install mcrypt
yum install php-mhash
yum install php-mcrypt

it working for me!!! RHEL 5.4 i'm using