# How Do I Install LAMP on RHEL 64 bit Including Mcrypt?

Tags: lamp, installation, mcrypt

Does anyone know of a good way to install LAMP on an RHEL 64 bit server which includes mcrypt? I went the manual route, and libmcrypt was not found even though it had been installed. I've tried every posted way on several forums with no success. I tried this:

[How to install mcrypt on RHEL5](https://serverfault.com/questions/124736/how-to-install-mcrypt-on-rhel5)

Especially the part where the poster suggests to install DAG rpm. I did that, but yum install mcrypt shows there is no package to install. Then I read elsewhere that even if it did install that I would need the 64 bit version. Can anyone help????

Answer (score 2):

I may be mistaken but i believe the package is **php-mcrypt**, not mcrypt.

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

with the DAG repo installed should do the trick.